# Upload file to UNC path from Blazor Server app

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app and I followed some Microsoft example code to upload files to a local path on my C drive which works fine:

```
   string path = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "MediaFiles", file.Name);
   await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
   await file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize).CopyToAsync(fs);
```

This will eventually go to other environments for testing and the production.  For that, we have shared directories on the servers.  In my test, I changed the path to a UNC path:

```
var root = "\\SomeRemoteServer";
var folder = "destinationFolder";

string path =  string path = Path.Combine(root, folder, file.Name);
await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create); //This line throws the error
await file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize).CopyToAsync(fs);
```

The line marked above throws this error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the
> path 'C:\<remoteServerName>\<foldername>\<fileName>'.'

I don't know why it is putting a "C:\" in front of the path.
Is there any way to avoid this?  Am I just going about this the wrong way for a UNC path?  I run this using F5, do I need to set it up to run in IIS as an application and have a virtual directory?
Just to note that the directory exists and can be accessed from my local machine with a UNC path.  There is no access/permissions error

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Remember that "\" is the escape character. Maybe in the environment you're running this when it sees "\SomeRemoteServer" it just automatically puts "C:" on the front. Does it work if you use `var root = @"\\SomeRemoteServer";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using:

```
var root = "\\SomeRemoteServer";
var folder = "destinationFolder";
string path = Path.Combine(root, folder, file.Name);
```

The value of `path` will actually be "\SomeRemoteServer\destinationFolder\?". Note that the "\" actually causes the slash to be escaped, not doubled as it should be in a UNC path. It appears that the FileStream object will then interpret "\SomeRemoteServer\destinationFolder\?" as "C:\SomeRemoteServer\destinationFolder\?" because it is using a local absolute path reference and the web app is running on the C: drive. You have a couple options.

Option 1 - use a string verbatim identifier when defining your root:

```
var root = @"\\SomeRemoteServer";
```

Option 2 - escape both of the UNC slashes:

```
var root = "\\\\SomeRemoteServer";
```

Comment: Thank you Lex !!

I used your Option #2. I used that because I am actually reading the path and folder from the appSettings.json file so I needed the double escape sequence.  I'm sure option 1 would work if I was defining the variables in the code behind.